# cakephp 2 multiple OR conditions while retrieving data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using multiple OR conditions in my find function, but cakephp overrides it and takes only the latest OR condition, which is very disturbing. Each or conditions focus a different table. This is my custom find function:

```
 $studies = $this -> Study -> find('studyWithSequence',array(
        'joins' => array(
            array('table' => 'executed_study_tables', // Table name
              'alias' => 'ExecutedStudyTable',
              'type' => 'LEFT',
              'conditions' => array(
                  'ExecutedStudyTable.study_id = Study.id', // Mention join condition here
              )
          )
       ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Study.user_id' => $cId,
            'OR'=>array(
                array('Study.state'=>'active'),
                array('Study.state'=>'rehearsal')
            ),                
            'SubjectFilter.studyCode'=>null,
            'SubjectFilter.m'=>1,
            'SubjectFilter.f'=>1,
            'SubjectFilter.age18_24'=>1,
            'SubjectFilter.age25_34'=>1,
            'SubjectFilter.age35_44'=>1,
            'SubjectFilter.age45_54'=>1,
            'SubjectFilter.age55plus'=>1,
            'OR'=>array(
                'NOT'=>array(
                    array('ExecutedStudyTable.user_id'=>$user),
                ),
                array('ExecutedStudyTable.user_id'=>null)
            )                
        ),
    ));
```

Do you know how to keep both or conditions?
I appreciate your replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
Normally cakephp 2 concatenate all conditions with AND, but in my case you have to define the AND condition manually. Like this:

```
 $studies = $this -> Study -> find('studyWithSequence',array(
        'joins' => array(
            array('table' => 'executed_study_tables',
              'alias' => 'ExecutedStudyTable',
              'type' => 'LEFT',
              'conditions' => array(
                  'ExecutedStudyTable.study_id = Study.id',
              )
          )
       ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Study.user_id' => $cId,
            'OR'=>array(
                array('Study.state'=>'active'),
                array('Study.state'=>'rehearsal')
            ),                
            'SubjectFilter.studyCode'=>null,
            'SubjectFilter.m'=>1,
            'SubjectFilter.f'=>1,
            'SubjectFilter.age18_24'=>1,
            'SubjectFilter.age25_34'=>1,
            'SubjectFilter.age35_44'=>1,
            'SubjectFilter.age45_54'=>1,
            'SubjectFilter.age55plus'=>1,
            'AND'=>array(
            'OR'=>array(
                'NOT'=>array(
                    array('ExecutedStudyTable.user_id'=>$user),
                ),
                array('ExecutedStudyTable.user_id'=>null)
            )         
            )       
        ),
    ));
```